# What all things can be stuffed inside a controller in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, desktop-application, mvp

I was going through the articles describing the MVC pattern. None of them were clear on explaining the role of Controller in MVC. Some says Controller can make changes to the view such as disabling a button or changing the text color whereas some says any changes to  the view should be done inside view only. Can you please give me tips on the following question?

1) Can any change pertaining to the view be done inside the controller?

2) What not should be written inside a controller?

3) It is right to say "View should do all the changes by itself when a new recordset is generated by the model, as the view queries model directly, and controller is not involved in this transaction?"

4) I have heard this statement about MVC "In current version of windows application development. View is capable to handle the event(like button press) and the controller is called when needed.It is stupid to delegate the event listening to the controller now." Doesn't this sound more like a MVP?

Thanks. Hoping to get some help here.

Comment: desktop app. I would  also like to know what difference it will make in web. Thanks,

Comment: About the controller; it's more like a decision-maker. Once the model and view have been created/coded, the controller (acting in line with what your page aims to do) will tell the model what it needs to do, and then take the results from that and pass it to the view which, in turn, can (depending on how you code your view) be told how to display the results passed to it...

Comment: @Nonym Ok.Thanks. So "view querying model directly for data after model's state is changed" said by some articles is not true.

Comment: On the web, obviously, the controller responds not to clicks, etc. but to HTTP requests.  It's much more decoupled.  You also don't have the opportunity to use listeners, but depend on the view to call the right actions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

1) The controller changes the data provided to the view, so in a way, yes. The view should just manage the *presentation* of the data provided to it by the controller.

2) The controller should contain all code to handle any actions taken by the user.  Depending on the size of your application, the controller can hand the action off to a business layer to do the work then gather view data once the business layer is complete and hand it back to the view.  Or, if you don't have a business layer, it can do the work directly.

3) In true MVC, the view should not have access to the model directly.  The controller should create *view* objects from the model and pass them to the view.  In any case, the view should *never* do any real work other than presentation.

4) I don't know MVP so cannot answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Controller responsibility is primarily "execute an action, choose an appropriate view, provide some data to that view and return the view to a user".

2) As MVC tries to separate presentation logic and UI rendering, I believe, controller shouldn't attempt to perform any of view responsibilities: listening to UI events or pre-formatting of values `dateString = data.ToString('YYYY-MM')` - that's all should go to view.

3) in MVC view knows all about a model - model is rendered by view without any controller involvement (that's primary 'issue' fixed by MVP, where view should and model should unbound as much as possible). However it's not recommended for view to query model directly. Instead, all data changes should be reported to view by model using Observer pattern. 
Consider the following  - 
[schema from wikipedia article](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/ModelViewControllerDiagram2.svg) - dashed line from model to view indicates that fact. Just keep in mind that model is more *viewmodel* here and shouldn't really be a part of BL layer.

So here scenario could be the following:

- User clicks "add item"
- View sends request to the controller with the item data
- Controller makes call to BL, which makes changes to the model (adds new item to the list).
- Model fires "updated" event to the view (or "error" event, if there are some issues in underlying layers)
- View updates UI according to changes reported.

4) The statement is perfectly true. In MVC you shouldn't do that. I assume, in MVP you shouldn't do that as well - I mean, listening to events from UI directly. That should be done either by forwarding event by view; or using a platform-independent view representation, like

```
inderface IMyGridView
{
    event ItemEvent AddItemClick;
}
```

(which doesn't make sense for MVC, as view is pretty much independent from a controller and mostly all view actions are result in calls to controller).